# Magento 2: Order getCreatedAt() returns null?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, orders, sales-order, dependency-injection

I meet a very strange situation while working with event observer in Magento 2.

My custom module hooked into `sales_order_save_after` (which returns `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order`), and its magic methods work fine but `getCreatedAt()`

The only way to get date time in this case is using this `getCreatedAtFormatted()` instead of `getCreatedAt()`.

Anyone can please tell me what was happening?

Comment: `getCreatedAtFormatted` uses `getCreatedAt` to create DateTime instance. So if `getCreatedAt` returns `null` and that is passed to `getCreatedAtFormatted`, then you are just getting current day's date not order created_at date.

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov Yes, I read it before. But what was happnened? Why it can become `null`?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, were you ever able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

See how `getCreatedAtFormatted` is declared:

```
public function getCreatedAtFormatted($format)
{
    return $this->timezone->formatDateTime(
        new \DateTime($this->getCreatedAt()),
        $format,
        $format,
        null,
        $this->timezone->getConfigTimezone('store', $this->getStore())
    );
}
```

It uses `$this->getCreatedAt()` to create `DateTime` and if you create `DateTime` like `new \DateTime(null)` you get current date.

The above means that if you have no value for `created_at` data of order, you are still going to get valid `\DateTime` object.

This is why `getCreatedAtFormatted` works and `getCreatedAt` is not.

Now all you need to figure out is why order is lacking created at value.

My guess is, that `created_at` is added by a timestamp update in the table, and to get its value, you may need to call `$order->load($order->getId())`

Answer (score 0):

I am probably posting too late but try hooking to

> 'checkout_submit_all_after' instead of 'sales_order_save_after'

Just had a similar issue and found out that

`setCreatedAt()` is called after `'sales_order_save_after'` is fired.